# Externalizing configurationdoes not work with full file name in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, externalizing

I am trying to learn Externalizing strings in **Spring 4.0.6 RELEASE**. In my beans configuration, I have following configuration for message resource.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basename="classpath:messages" />
```

My message resource is under **main/src/resources/messages.properties** in classpath.

The above configuration works fine, but when I use the full name "messages.properties" in the configuration (**p:basename="classpath:messages.properties"**) , then loading the message resource fails!

Anyone has a clue why is it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in Spring's documentation:

> Set a single basename, following the basic ResourceBundle convention
>   of not specifying file extension or language codes

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasename(java.lang.String)